# Total page number with itextpdf

Tags: itext, itextpdf

I am using itextpdf-5.5.6 for publish my data.
I'm trying to set page numbers in `PdfPCell` of my pdf using following format : **page_num/total_page_num**
For this I use `PdfTemplate` object filling inside total page number before close document.
It warks, but `PdfTemplate` exceeds `PdfPCell` border.
Is it possible that all content of cell stay inside of cell properly ?

```
PdfTemplate pageNumTemplate;
    @Test
    public void quick_test() throws FileNotFoundException, DocumentException {
        String filename = "C:\\test.pdf";
        File file = new File(filename);
        Document document = new Document();
        PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(filename));
        PageNumberEvent pageNumberEvent = new PageNumberEvent();
        writer.setPageEvent(pageNumberEvent);
        document.open();
        for(int i = 0; i < 10000; i++){
            document.add(new Paragraph("This is my paragraph"));
            document.newPage();
        }
        document.close();

    }

    public class PageNumberEvent extends PdfPageEventHelper {
        @Override
        public void onEndPage(PdfWriter writer, Document document) {
            if(pageNumTemplate == null){
                pageNumTemplate = writer.getDirectContent().createTemplate(0.1f, 0.1f);
            }
            PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(1);
            table.setSpacingBefore(50);
            Paragraph para = new Paragraph();
            Chunk pageNum = new Chunk(writer.getPageNumber() + "/");
            para.add(pageNum);

            Image totalPageNumImg = null;
            try {
                totalPageNumImg = Image.getInstance(pageNumTemplate);
            } catch (BadElementException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            Chunk totalPageNumImgChunk = new Chunk(totalPageNumImg, 0, -1, true);
            para.add(totalPageNumImgChunk);
            para.setIndentationLeft(370);
            PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell(para);
            cell.addElement(para);
            table.addCell(cell);
            try {
                document.add(table);
            } catch (DocumentException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void onCloseDocument(PdfWriter writer,Document document) {
            String totalPageNumString = String.valueOf(writer.getPageNumber() - 1);
            float widthPoint = totalPageNumString.length() * 10;
            float heightPoint = totalPageNumString.length() * 20;
            Phrase totalPageNumPhrase = new Phrase(totalPageNumString);
            Rectangle templRect = pageNumTemplate.getBoundingBox();
            Rectangle rectangle = new Rectangle(templRect.getLeft(), templRect.getBottom(), widthPoint, heightPoint + 2);
            pageNumTemplate.setBoundingBox(rectangle);
            ColumnText.showTextAligned(pageNumTemplate, Element.ALIGN_LEFT, totalPageNumPhrase, 0, 1, 0);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Early, in the first `onEndPage` call, you create a minute template (0.1x0.1) to start with

```
pageNumTemplate = writer.getDirectContent().createTemplate(0.1f, 0.1f);
```

which fits into your cell. At the end though, in `onCloseDocument`, after everything has been layout'ed to a fixed position, you resize this template which makes it grow to the left:

```
Rectangle templRect = pageNumTemplate.getBoundingBox();
Rectangle rectangle = new Rectangle(templRect.getLeft(), templRect.getBottom(), widthPoint, heightPoint + 2);
pageNumTemplate.setBoundingBox(rectangle);
```

If you want your template to remain in your table cell, you have to initialize it with a width which most likely will be enough to hold the number of pages, e.g.

```
pageNumTemplate = writer.getDirectContent().createTemplate(30f, 0.1f);
```

Here you may have to play around a bit...

---

As the OP indicated in a comment, not only keeping *all content of cell stay inside of cell* is required but the content also is expected to be right aligned in the cell.

This second requirement obviously cannot be fulfilled by the OP's code which draws the number of pages into the template using `ALIGN_LEFT`. Furthermore it does not mix and match with resizing the template on the right size because it has already been positioned on the pages.

To fulfill it, therefore, the OP should

- horizontally initialize the template with a size large enough for any expected number of pages (`onEndPage`);
- fill the table cell with right alignment (instead of some pseudo right alignment by means of `setIndentationLeft`) (`onEndPage`);
- leave the horizontal size of the template as is (`onCloseDocument`); and
- show the number of pages *right aligned* to the right template border (`onCloseDocument`).

Comment: If I use fixed width it will give the margins.

Comment: I want the right margin remains fixed and it never exceeds

Comment: Hhmmm, that sounds like you might want to `showTextAligned` with `Element.ALIGN_RIGHT` and not change the initial box size at all.